# Importing another file while I do not know a name of variable to import

Tags: python, import

*Main.py*

```
current_code = rQbbUM3GDMrHw31uZQPYfsDdt
```

*current_code* has been generated in *Main.py*. In *database.py* variable *curent_code* has the same value as in *Main.py*. 
*database.py*

```
QbbUM3GDMrHw31uZQPYfsDdt = {'a':'Y', 'b':'U', 'c':'0',}
```

I need to get a list of keys and values from *database.py*. I tried with

```
import database as db
key_list = list(db.current_code.keys())
value_list = list(db.current_code.values())
```

But this does not work, because current_code is not a variable in *database.py*, but in *Main.py*. Code from above is passed in *Main.py*. I need to get this list in *Main.py*, because every time I run this program, a new current_code is generated.

Comment: Why can you not import `current_code` from `main`?

Comment: you do not understand. Value of **current_code** is a variable in *database.py* I need to import variable from *database.py*, that is a value of current_code in *Main.py*

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure you have imported main.py in the database file and also remember that in main.py current_code is "rQbbUM3GDMrHw31uZQPYfsDdt", while in database.py, you have a variable called "QbbUM3GDMrHw31uZQPYfsDdt" which do not have "r" at the start as current_code has